# $.ajax like function for Inferno js?

Tags: javascript

How do I post data using React and Angular?

Is there has function like $.ajax for Inferno js?

I mean I need just like this post function for Inferno js

```
$.ajax{
url:"test.php",
type:"POST",
cache:false,
success...
```

And i also want full documentation about Inferno js?

Answer (score 1):

React and Infero are libraries for building user interfaces. If you are following the MVC pattern, then they are primarily responsible for the View.

The `$.ajax` function is about getting data. In MVC terms it forms part of the Model (or possibly the Controller depending on if you subscribe the the fat or skinny controller design pattern).

React and Infero don't care how the model works, they just take data from it.

So add jQuery to your application and use `$.ajax`, or don't and use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` directly, or find a different library entirely. It doesn't matter to React or Inferno.